# Less (css) - possible adding multiple tags and properties in one block?

Tags: css, less

Styling css with **Less.js** preprocessor I have something similar to this:

```
 a,a:hover,a:focus,a:active,a:link,a:visited {
    text-decoration: hsl(46, 27%, 5%);
    font-weight: inherit;
    ... <other props>
    border-bottom: 1px solid hsl(200, 99%, 10%);
}
```

Is it possible using Less to wrap the entire block above in some sort of class, function, ruleset, or variable and to use it everywhere else, when needed (in other classes, styles, selectors, tags) ?

Example, whishing something like:

```
.myHrefStyle() {
  
   a,a:hover,...{
      text-decoration: hsl(46, 27%, 5%);
      ... 
      border-bottom: 1px solid hsl(200, 99%, 10%);
   }

}
```

then reusing it elsewhere:

```
.otherClass {
    .myHrefStyle()
}
```

Comment: I think this is what you want https://lesscss.org/features/#mixins-feature

Answer (score 0):

Detached rulesets should work. [Documentation](https://lesscss.org/features/#detached-rulesets-feature)

```less
// Declare detached ruleset
@myHrefStyle: {

    a,
    a:hover,
    a:focus,
    a:active,
    a:link,
    a:visited {
        text-decoration: hsl(46, 27%, 5%);
        font-weight: inherit;
        border-bottom: 1px solid hsl(200, 99%, 10%);
    }

};

.otherClass {
    @myHrefStyle(); // Use detached ruleset
}
```